# 13 type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I'm trying to send data between worksheets. When I run the code below, I get a 13 mismatch error on the IncidentReport variable. On the source sheet these ranges are numerical but one cell is a date (so number, date, number). I have tried to declare the IncidentReport as a string, integer, and long but I keep getting this error. What is the correct variable for this?

```
Private Sub Update_Click()
Dim AgentName As String
Dim IncidentReport As Long
Dim MyData As Workbook

'Names variable
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
    AgentName = Range("C2")
    IncidentReport = Range("D1:F1")
 'Opens master workbook
Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashley.graham\Field_AgentFolder\Incident Reports\Test folder\Incident reports 2018.xlsx")

'Calls sheet and selects cell
Worksheets("Incident Reports").Select
    Worksheets("Incident Reports").Range("a1").Select
    'finds next blank row for data entry
    RowCount = Worksheets("Incident Reports").Range ("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("Incident Reports").Range("A1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = IncidentReport
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = AgentName
    End With
    MyData.Save


End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("D1:F1")` returns an array. Can't be  converted to type `Long`, hence the error.

Comment: You're trying to assign the values of three separate cells into a single variable:  cells D1, E1, and F1. This is why you're getting a type mismatch. You either need three variables or change the `IncidentReport` to a `Range`

Comment: I tried range but I get an runtime error 91- Object variable or With block variable not set. I just did a search for that error where it was suggested that "Set" be placed before IncidentReport = Range("D1:F1"). That allowed the code to run, but the numbers in D1:F1 didn't print to the cell in the master workbook.

Comment: Is `Worksheets("Incident Reports")` in the workbook you open in the code?

Comment: As `IncidentReport` are the values held in three cells `D1:F1` what action do you perform to put the three values into a single cell (`.Offset(RowCount, 0)`)?  Add them, concatenate them, just use the highest value?

Comment: Yes the worksheet is called "Incident reports". I was concatenating them the values in the cells. Together the data forms a unique number for the incident report.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

    Dim AgentName As String
    Dim IncidentReport As Range
    Dim MyData As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        AgentName = .Range("C2")
        Set IncidentReport = .Range("D1:F1")
    End With

    Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashley.graham\Field_AgentFolder\Incident Reports\Test folder\Incident reports 2018.xlsx")

    With MyData.Worksheets("Incident Reports")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = IncidentReport.Cells(1) 'This will put the first cell value here as don't know what you want.
        .Cells(LastRow, 2) = AgentName
    End With

    MyData.Save

End Sub
```